# Adding some Nuget packages gives error

Tags: nuget, monodevelop

I am using `MonoDevelop GUI 5.10 Build 871` under `Fedora 26`. When I try to add to the project `Reactive Extensions`through the `Nuget` GUI, I get

```
Adding System.Reactive.Core...
The 'System.Reactive.Core 3.1.1' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.7.0'.
```

How do I resolve this?

Edit:

If I try to add nuget to the command line, there are two problems as show below:

1. I seem to get the same version that is installed in the monodevelop GUI
2. I get a strange error at the end.

Output

```
[idf@localhost Debug]$ sudo nuget update -self
[sudo] password for idf: 
sudo: nuget: command not found
[idf@localhost Debug]$ nuget update -self
bash: nuget: command not found...
Install package 'nuget' to provide command 'nuget'? [N/y] y


 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Loading list of packages.... 
The following packages have to be installed:
 nuget-2.8.7-3.fc26.x86_64  Package manager for .Net/Mono development platform
Proceed with changes? [N/y] y


 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Waiting for authentication... 
 * Waiting in queue... 
 * Downloading packages... 
 * Requesting data... 
 * Testing changes... 
 * Installing packages... 
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Error: TrustFailure (Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED)

[idf@localhost Debug]$
```

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/status-of-monodevelop-xamarin-studio-253da80d022c Don't use MonoDevelop 5.x any more.

Comment: That is terrific. I was able to install MD 7.x and add nuget packages by following your link to here: https://github.com/cra0zy/monodevelop-run-installer

Answer (score 1):

Update your nuget version.

```
nuget update -self
```

> Update packages to latest available versions. **This command also updates NuGet.exe itself.**

Note: You might have to use `sudo` depending upon how it was originally installed.

Comment: See added "Edit" section in the OP.

Comment: @Ivan What version of Mono do you have installed? Assuming "old" as newer versions support TLS1.2 via Google's boringSSL. You can manually download and replace your `nuget.exe` (https://www.nuget.org/downloads)